# C++ Align 5 byte structs to cacheline

Tags: c++, memory, data-structures, alignment

I'm developing a CPU-FPGA co-processing framework, so I need complete control over the alignment of my data. I have a data structure that only requires 5 bytes:

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed))  {
    uint32_t dst;
    uint8_t weight;
} edg_t;
```

My FPGA interface can read at 1 cache-line (64 bytes) per cycle (200 million reads / second). It is critical to my performance that I cram as many elements into one cache-line, so padding the struct is out of the question.

5 bytes : 12 elements / read
8 bytes : 8 elements / read (padded)
padding -> 1.5x performance reduction

However, I cannot have a struct straddle the edge between cache-lines that requires that I build logic on the FPGA to constantly shift the read data.

My current solution when building the buffer looks like this:

```
int num_elements = 1000;
int num_cachelines = num_elements / 12 + 1;

uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[num_cachelines * 64]
uint8_t* buf_ptr = buffer - 4;

for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
    if (i % 12 == 0) buf_ptr += 4; //skip the last 4 bytes of each cache-line

    edg_t* edg_ptr = (edg_t*) buf_ptr;
    edg_ptr->dst = i; //example, I have random generators here
    edg_ptr->weight = i % 256;
    buf_ptr++;

}
```

Now that was fine when the FPGA was doing all the work on its own, now I want the FPGA and CPU to cooperate. this means that the CPU now has to read the buffer as well.

I was wondering if there exists a better way to have the compiler handle the padding automatically or will I have to manually skip the bytes every-time like I did in the buffer creation code above?

Comment: Your allocation for `buffer` is not guaranteed to return 64-byte aligned memory unless you provide a custom `::operator new` that does that.  That can throw off what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you'll create this buffer structure once and that you then populated it over and over again for the FPGA to read (or vice-a-versa). If so, this layout should work:

```
constexpr size_t cacheline_size = 64;
constexpr size_t num_elements = 1000;

struct __attribute__ ((packed)) edg_t  {
    /*volatile*/ uint32_t dst;   // volatile if the FPGA writes too
    /*volatile*/ uint8_t weight;
};

constexpr size_t elements_per_cachline = cacheline_size/sizeof(edg_t);
constexpr size_t num_cachelines = num_elements / elements_per_cachline + 1;

struct alignas(cacheline_size) cacheline_t {
    std::array<edg_t, elements_per_cachline> edg;
    inline auto begin() { return edg.begin(); }
    inline auto end() { return edg.end(); }
};

struct cacheline_collection_t {
    std::array<cacheline_t, num_cachelines> cl;
    inline void* address_for_fpga() { return this; }
    inline auto begin() { return cl.begin(); }
    inline auto end() { return cl.end(); }
};

int main() {
    cacheline_collection_t clc;
    std::cout << "edg_t                 : "
       << alignof(edg_t) << " " << sizeof(clc.cl[0].edg[0]) << "\n";
    std::cout << "cacheline_t           : "
       << alignof(cacheline_t) << " " << sizeof(clc.cl[0]) << "\n";
    std::cout << "cacheline_collection_t: "
       << alignof(cacheline_collection_t) << " " << sizeof(clc) << "\n";

    // access
    for(auto& cl : clc) {
        for(auto& edg : cl) {
            std::cout << edg.dst << " " << (unsigned)edg.weight << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The [assembly @ godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/yb-i9G) looks nice. The inner loop has been completely inlined to 12 code blocks where it adds 5 to the `rax` offset for each block. Then it goes to the next cacheline (conditionally) in 3 operations:

```
    add     rax, 64
    cmp     rax, rcx
    jne     .LBB0_1
```